# Adding database index for my Rails app

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, indexing

I'm using MySQL and need to add some indexing to my tables for better performance.

One of my common queries is something like this:

```
arrs = @book.items.where("type = 'A' and status not in ('cancelled','notransportation')").order("item_date, item_time asc")
```

How would you suggest adding an index that would help with such a query?

Answer (score 1):

Collect the raw SQL query that's being run from your application's logs, and then use `SELECT EXPLAIN` to figure out where to add your indexes.

I found [this tutorial](http://schimpf.es/mysql-explain-tutorial/) and [this slideshow](http://www.slideshare.net/phpcodemonkey/mysql-explain-explained) on `SELECT EXPLAIN`, which should help. Good luck!